# Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'DateOperators' - MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want to add the below code to my project.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
       project(from(field("dayActivity.type", "dayActivity.type"), 
                    field("tid"))).
               and(DateOperators.dateOf("activityDate").toString("%Y-%m-%d")).as("yearMonthDay"),
       match(where("yearMonthDay").is("2017-11-05").and("tid").is("12345678"))
);
```

I am not even able to add DateOperators.class or the particular maven dependency in my project.
It is showing an error
while importing :

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.DateOperators;
```

Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'DateOperators'

--using a 4.0.5 MongoDB version.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To project a `date` field as string of format `"%Y-%m-%d"`use this syntax:

```
project()
    .and(DateOperators.DateToString
        .dateOf("activityDate")
        .toString("%Y-%m-%d"))
    .as("yearMonthDay")
```

And, you are looking to import `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.DateOperators`. This worked fine with Spring Data MongoDB 2.3 and MongoDB Server v4.2.

For example, the date field `activityDate` with value `ISODate("2020-09-23T12:10:15.710Z")` is projected as a field with name  `yearMonthDay` with value `"2020-09-23"`.

Comment: NOTE: The aggregation operator `dateToString` is introduced with MongoDB v3.0.